# How to find duplicate files with same content, but with different names using python?

Tags: python, file, duplicates

I often end up with duplicate files with same content, but with different names while doing the literature study. How to find and delete the duplicate files using python?

Comment: Write a script to md5sum each file, find files with same md5sum and delete.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [fdupes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes) tool to find duplicate files in a given set of directories first and then perform the delete operation. [fdupes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes) searches the given path for duplicate files. Duplicate files are identified by comparing file sizes and MD5 signatures, followed by a byte-by-byte comparison.

1. Check duplicate files first:

```sh
fdupes -rf . | grep -v '^$' > files.txt
```

2. Then delete:

```sh
xargs -a files.txt rm -v
```

If you don't want keep the list of duplicates in a separate file and just need to delete all copies except the first one, you can issue:

```sh
fdupes -r -f . | grep -v '^$' | xargs rm -v
```

If you want to delete duplicate files in the current directory one by one manually and need confirmation right before each delete, issue:

```sh
fdupes -r -d .
```

The `fdupes` command isn’t typically installed by default, but it’s available in most of the Linux distribution’s repositories. If you don't have it installed, just run:

```sh
brew install fdupes         # For Mac OS X
sudo apt-get install fdupes # Debian based systems such as Ubuntu and Linux Mint
sudo yum install fdupes     # On CentOS/RHEL and Fedora based systems
sudo dnf install fdupes     # On Fedora 22 onwards
```

To get `fdupes` installed on SLE distributions, you need to add repository first.

For SLE 11 SP4 run the following as root:

```sh
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:paddg/SLE_11_SP4/home:paddg.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install fdupes
```

For SLE 11 SP3 run the following as root:

```sh
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:paddg/SLE_11_SP3/home:paddg.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install fdupes
```

If you would like to write up something in bash, you can do it like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -A dupes
shopt -s globstar

for file in **; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
   
  read cksm _ < <(md5sum "$file")
  if ((dupes[$cksm]++)); then 
    echo "rm $file" # Remove echo to perform the delete
  fi
done
```

Remember, this requires `bash version 4.x` for the ability to use associative arrays and recursive searching. But this is fair enough to handle any filename and recursive search.